# Using the TFS 2012 API, how do I get the email address of a user?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying to get the email address of a particular user in TFS 2012 using the API.  I have set the users Preferred Email address in the Profile section.  I have done plenty of searching online and have the following code.

```
var userId = "myUserId";
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, tfsCerd);
var managementService = collection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

var member =
    managementService
        .ReadIdentity(
            IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,
            userId,
            MembershipQuery.Direct,
            ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);

var emailAddress = member.GetAttribute("Mail", null)
```

This code is both a success and a failure.  It is a success in that it successfully retrieves the specified user; however, the problem is that the Email attribute is blank.  When I analyzed the member variable, I noticed the "Mail" attribute was listed there and it was empty.  I then noticed there were two other attributes called "ConfirmedNotificationAddress" and "CustomNotificationAddress" that had my preferred email address correctly in there.

I am wondering why I can't seem to get the "Mail" variable to load properly with the preferred email address as I will need this code to work on a lot of peoples servers.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Mail` instead of `Email` for the attribute name - that works for me.

Also, if that doesn't work, check the results of `member.GetProperties()` - maybe that will give you the right name to use.

For me, `GetProperty("Mail")` also worked.

Comment: That was a typo in my original question.  I had meant to put "Mail".  So, the "Mail" variable is returning as an empty string and the two other variables are returning the correct email address.  Is it possible that this Mail variable comes from a different place than the Profile section?

Comment: It may come from Active Directory - you can try using ADExplorer.exe (from Sysinternals Suite) to look at the attributes of the users there.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same problem, I found a work around by getting my users email address from AD using the following code.

```
    public string GetUserEmail(string username)
    {
        using (var pctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pctx, username))
            {
                return up != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.EmailAddress) ? up.EmailAddress : string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

But then I found that it would throw an exception when my user was not in my domain. So this code helped me have an a second source. If I didn't find in AD i would go and use the IdentityManagementService.

```
    public TeamFoundationIdentity GetUserByAccountName(string account)
    {
        var ims = _tfServer.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
        return ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName, account, MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);
    }
```

Then I would simply use this execution.

```
    var ownerMail = GetUserEmail(checkinEvent.Resource.CheckedInBy.DisplayName);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ownerMail))
    {
       ownerMail = GetUserByAccountName(checkinEvent.Resource.CheckedInBy.DisplayName).GetProperty("Mail").ToString();
    }
```