# How to retrieve user email from username in PowerShell for TFS?

Tags: tfs, identity-management

I am using TFS IIdentityManagementService2 in powershell to get User details of a user object (Assigned To / Created By field). I am able to get User Unique name like Domain\username. How do I get email id of the user now?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155773/get-email-and-display-name-from-alias-in-visual-studio-team-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **GetProperty** method on your `TeamFoundationIdentity` object with the "**Mail**" key:

```
user.GetProperty("Mail")
```

A sample code for your reference:

```
private static readonly Func<TeamFoundationIdentity, string> _emailSelector =
            identity =>
            {
                object value;
                if (identity.TryGetProperty("ConfirmedNotificationAddress", out value) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)value))
                {
                    return (string) value;
                }

                return (string) identity.GetProperty("Mail");
            };
```

You could also take a look at below related articles:

- [Using the TFS 2012 API, how do I get the email address of a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911368/using-the-tfs-2012-api-how-do-i-get-the-email-address-of-a-user)
- [Get TFS User List (Mail, Sid, Account, Domain)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/01/14/tfs-api-part-4-get-tfs-user-list-mail-sid-account-domain/) (including the concept of all Identitys in TFS )

Comment: Perfect. It served my purpose. Thank you Patrick-MSFT. :) However I did not use the null parameter in GetProperty. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @dia Sorry my mistake, it's another method [GetAttribute Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.teamfoundationidentity.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) which should also work, there is a default value in that method. I mixed up both. Have edited the answer.